# How to send mails to marketing list members with some extractions (CRM Dynamics)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I would like to send an email to the members of a marketing list A with some extractions.

Marketing list A: 1600
Marketing list B: 100

However, members in marketing list B are also in marketing A. I want to send emails to marketing list A without the members in marketing list B.
Would it be possible to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you would be following:

1. Create List C.
2. Copy members from A to C. (Add members based on advanced Find Query)
3. Exclude from C members from B. (Remove members based on advanced Find Query)

*Updated

Comment: Thank you for your help!I want to have a (A-B) list instead of (A+B) list.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I found your method effective, but then I realise that one of marketing list type is Contact while the other marketing list type is Account. This method may not be used. ;(

Comment: In this case your initial message "want to send emails to marketing list A without the members in marketing list B" is not the truth. Because you can't mix accounts and contacts in the same Marketing List. If you want your question to be answered rephrase it please.